# Passing generic parameters in a generic class

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to get something like below using generics in swift? Any help would be appreciated more than anything else.

```
class ABC {
   var title: String?
}

class Option: <T> {
   var name: String?
   var data: T?
}

let object1 = ABC()

let option = Option(name: "Test", data: object1)

// Getting data again
let data = option.data
```

Comment: `class Option: <T>` should be `class Option<T>`

Comment: @Sh_Khan: The answer that I was expecting wasn't in the examples that you marked duplicate. Infact the below answer is something that I require.. Can you please remove the duplicate tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use **`Generics`** in `Swift`.

```
protocol PPP {
    var title: String? {get set}
}

class ABC: PPP {
    var title: String?
}

class XYZ: PPP {
    var title: String?
}

class Option<T> {
    var name: String?
    var data: T?

    init(name: String?, data: T?) {
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
    }
}

let object1 = ABC()
let option1 = Option(name: "Test1", data: object1)

let object2 = XYZ()
let option2 = Option(name: "Test2", data: object2)
```

Since `classes` in `Swift` doesn't have a `default initializer`, so create one that accepts 2 parameters - `String?` and `T?`.

You can use `type(of:)` method to identify the `type` of an `object`.

```
print(type(of: option1.data)) //ABC
print(type(of: option2.data)) //XYZ
```

You can use **`protocol`** to access `title` in both `ABC` and `XYZ`.

Conform `ABC` and `XYZ` to `protocol PPP` and implement its `title` property in both `ABC` and `XYZ`.

```
print(option1.data?.title)
print(option2.data?.title)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to identify the dataType for data in the last line. How do I do that without type casting?

Comment: This is correct which I am already aware of. I am looking for something like: 

option1.data.title 

Can I directly access the variable with out checking its type? I guess that can be done using protocols?

Comment: Updated that too. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. That's a womnderful help. Does that mean I'll have to declare all the variables of classes ABC() and XYZ() in PPP protocol?

Comment: No. But the reverse is `true`. You need to implement mandatory `variables` and `methods` of `PPP` in `ABC` and `XYZ`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193718/discussion-between-amrit-sidhu-and-pgdev).

Comment: A little more confusion: Now its asks to add a "Any" suffix 

let option1 = Option<Any>(name: "Test1", data: object1)

That makes data of type any which is not letting me directly fetch the variables from data?

Comment: Add the same type in angular brackets that you are passing as data `let option1 = Option<ABC>(name: "Test1", data: object1)`

Comment: One question - Do you really need `class Option` now? I think your requirement is now satisfied using `protocol`. Check identify the use case.

Comment: Yes, class Option is required as it holds other properties related to a tableView.

Comment: Your answer is great!! This worked. But I got another problem. I do not want to add all of the properties of XYZ() into ABC(). However PPP protocol compels to add all properties.. Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: I was able to make it optional. Thanks Dude!!

Comment: Hi @PGDev Can you please try to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382822/uisearchbar-not-changing-search-icon-and-placeholder-color-for-ios-12-1?noredirect=1#comment99366474_56382822