# UISearchBar not changing search icon and placeholder color for iOS 12.1

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have tried every approach to change the color of search icon and placeholder text search bar but nothing worked. Can anyone please help me out!

This is the implementation I am following for search bar.

```
func configureSearchBar() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Suche", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])

    searchController.searchBar.setText(color: .white)
    searchController.searchBar.setTextField(color: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2))
    searchController.searchBar.setPlaceholderText(color: .white)
    searchController.searchBar.setSearchImage(color: .white)
    searchController.searchBar.setClearButton(color: .white)
}

extension UISearchBar {

func getTextField() -> UITextField? { return value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField }
func setText(color: UIColor) { if let textField = getTextField() { textField.textColor = color } }
func setPlaceholderText(color: UIColor) { getTextField()?.setPlaceholderText(color: color) }
func setClearButton(color: UIColor) { getTextField()?.setClearButton(color: color) }

func setTextField(color: UIColor) {
    guard let textField = getTextField() else { return }
    switch searchBarStyle {
    case .minimal:
        textField.backgroundColor = color
        textField.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    case .prominent, .default: textField.backgroundColor = color
    @unknown default: break
    }
}

func setSearchImage(color: UIColor) {
    guard let imageView = getTextField()?.leftView as? UIImageView else { return }
    imageView.tintColor = color
    imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
}
```

}

Comment: Please check this :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817330/how-to-change-inside-background-color-of-uisearchbar-component-on-ios
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699859/changing-the-color-of-the-icons-in-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uisearchbar

Comment: None of these solutions worked. I have already checked quite a lot many solutions. I feel there is a problem in the implementation that is restricting the color changes.

Comment: I think the code is working for all the version except 12.1 can you check this .?

Comment: Which one should I check?

Comment: In question all method should working in 12 and 11 version just try if it working good then this issue occur by apple and when it resolved it automatically working in your app.

Comment: I have face similar issue like in mail app navigation bar color same code is working for 11 but not in 12 :)

Comment: No that's not the case. There should be a fix to this problem.

Comment: You can try my extension as well in 11 version it should work because it working for me

Comment: Once please try in lower version it might working there so you can get some idea about this issue or wait for some response here some developer are see your question and answer better way ✌️

Comment: Sure, I'll wait for another answer.

Comment: Yes Great Happy Coding

Answer (score 3):

Try this way it change the seachbar placeholder color

```
     var searchTextField: UITextField? = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        if searchTextField!.responds(to: #selector(getter: UITextField.attributedPlaceholder)) {
            let attributeDict = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
            searchTextField!.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: attributeDict)
        }
```

OR

```
  extension UISearchBar
{

    func setMagnifyingGlassColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        // Search Icon
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as? UIImageView
        glassIconView?.image = glassIconView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        glassIconView?.tintColor = color
    }

    func setClearButtonColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        // Clear Button
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let crossIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.value(forKey: "clearButton") as? UIButton
        crossIconView?.setImage(crossIconView?.currentImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        crossIconView?.tintColor = color
    }

    func setPlaceholderTextColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = color
        let textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel = textFieldInsideSearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
        textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel?.textColor = color
    }
}
```

Comment: Its the same that I have shared above in the question.